# How to define sorter tab width in reduxframework?

Tags: php, redux, redux-framework

Hello Can you please help me to define a column width in redux-framework sorter??
Take a look at this code.

```
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'            => __( 'Page Manager', 'redux' ),
    'id'               => 'page-manager',
    'subsection' => true,
    'desc'  => __( 'These Settings will work only Landing Page, Now you can use any section on Landing Page.', 'redux' ),
    'customizer_width' => '700px',
    'icon'             => 'el el-home-alt',
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'opt-homepage-layout-landing',
            'type'     => 'sorter',
            'title'    => 'Landing Page Layout Manager',
            'desc'     => 'Organize how you want the layout to appear on the Home Page',
            'compiler' => 'true',
            'options'  => array(
                'disabled' => array(                        
                    'sliderv1' => 'LayerSlider Style 1',
                ),
                'enabled'  => array(
                    'sliderv2' => 'LayerSlider Style 2',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
) );
```

Now if we come to option then only shown LayerSlider but i want to show LayerSlider Style 1.
How its possible without custom css??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage this with custom CSS.
I have include custom CSS in WordPress Admin side. Other then that i have not find any solution. Just reply here to help others.